# Excel 2010 - Auto populate cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

below is sheet No1 & 2:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet2]

I would like to Automate excel so that it takes the inspection number from Sheet 1 (yellow cells) and put it in the appropriate location in sheet 2 (Red Cells).

For example: 1st yellow cell in sheet 1 is "Floor paint" in the "Entrance". now it should look for the cell in sheet 2 that falls in the intersection between "Floor paint" Column & "Entrance" row.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an array formula:

`=INDEX($C:$C,MAX(($A:$A=$F2)*($B:$B=G$1)*ROW($C:$C)))`

(as this is an array formula, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after inserting it).

[image]

Comment: that works perfect!!! but what if i had different inspection numbers at the same location and trade? ex: "Floor paint" - "Entrance": inspection number 22903 & 45524, how can i add both numbers in 1 cell

Comment: That's much more difficult:( Then you probably need to use a helper column, where you merge them first.

Comment: can you advise how that can be done?